# Wait before checking if statement..?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, settimeout, wait

I've got a slider kind of thing.
When clicked on the next button it will check if a variable is equal to a number. If the number is equal is will execute a function.

```
 var month = 0; //variable

 $("#nextbutton").live('click',function(event){
     month+=1;

     if(month == 1) {
         foto1();   
     }

     if(month == 2) {
         foto2();      
     }

     if(month == 3) {
         foto3();
     }

 )};
```

But I would like the code to 'wait' before going to the if-statement. Because it executes all these functions at the same time.
Because month == 1 is function 1. month == 2 is function 2 and so forth.

Comment: It has to wait 500ms before checking the if-statement. When a user is clicking quickly multiple times on the next button it executes functions at the same time. And I would like to execute one function at the same time. (maybe there is a better way to achieve that then using 'wait' or settimeout.

Answer (score 1):

```
var month = 0; //variable

$("#nextbutton").live('click',function(event){
var month = month+1;
setTimeout(function() {
     if(month == 1) {
         foto1();   
     }
    }, <time_in_ms_to_wait>)
});
```

Hope that helps.